# Image is stretching in imagebutton as per width and height

Tags: android, android-layout

This ImageButton is clickable.  I need to present this icon in center without stretch. Is there any way to add width and height or property? Please give me a idea. Thanks

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/usercalltab"/>
```

usercalltab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <solid android:color="#ffdbab" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                 <bitmap android:src="@drawable/search"/>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item>
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <item>
                 <bitmap android:src="@drawable/callme"/>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
        </item>
</selector>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you ever tried padding options ?

Comment: background is for the background of you button. As a background, it is supposed to stretch below the whole button. use src and scaleType instead (also, read the doc, imageButton extends ImageView, therefore it has all the same methods and attributes)

Comment: instead of background use android:src and use android:scaleType to scale or fit the image..

Comment: Please check my xml file also. If i use src, is possible to change picture image with background color?

Comment: with ImageButton, the button looks like the default button with an image on top (provided by the `android:src` attribute. You can change the button aspect with the `android:background` attribute. The **background** will stretch to the whole button, the **src** will scale according to the `scaleType` attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should split it into background and foreground image. It's much cleaner and re-usable.

If you want to achieve it without doing so, you may try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#ffdbab" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                 <bitmap android:src="@drawable/search" android:gravity="center" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                 <bitmap android:src="@drawable/callme" android:gravity="center" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Working perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

try like this:

```
<ImageButton
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/usercalltab"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
/>
```

or maybe `android:scaleType="center"`

one of those should be what you are looking for I think